# Forbidden cursor?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for the name of the "forbidden/cancel" cursor.

I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The values of `cursor` that represent what you're looking for are `not-allowed` and `no-drop`. These values are new to CSS3, so if you need browser compatibility you should specify an image instead.

Comment: If it's a forbidden/cancel option not linked to drag and drop, semantically it's better to use `not-allowed`.

Comment: @Promo: Indeed. Someone else might butt in and say "but semantics are irrelevant in CSS!" but I agree with you. I don't know why I didn't edit my answer after the first comment pointed it out, but now I have.

Answer (score 35):

The css  `cursor: not-allowed;` also works.

Answer (score 14):

here is complete sample:

```css
.not-allowed {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="not-allowed" class="not-allowed" disabled />
```